# Compare string date to date format field dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm new and learning Crystal reports quickly. I need a formula that would be able to compare a string field date ex (4211990) to a date field format ex (4/21/1990) . Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Try `ToText('4211990', "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: @rs. ToText() does not accept strings as a parameter...Also, lower-case "m" in a format string means minutes, not months. I think you meant `ToText({table.date},"Mdyyyy")`

Comment: @Dagz200 What country uses dd/MM/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

`ToText({table.date},"Mdyyyy")` (per Ryan's comment)

Answer answer questions, don't comment answer questions :(